# Cypress Conditional Test, else statement is not executed, fails test

Tags: javascript, cypress

Need a help on Cypress Conditional testing, for else statement is not executing 
I have scenario, where in if single or multiple child elements available in parent element, close all child element, if no child element exit /skip command
Parent # : Parent
Child Element:  All Child Element has class = "child-class-in-scope"
my code as follows , test fails when if statement return false , rather i expect to go to else condition ,  what mistake I am doing here, tried using some counters too

```
var count 
 if(cy.get(parent).should('have.descendants', '[class="child-class-in-scope"]'))
    {
        cy.log("There are child element available");
        count = 1            
    })
else{
      cy.log ("NO CHild element")
      count= 0
}
if count = 1 {
    cy.get(child_element)
    .each(function($el, i){
    cy.log($el, i)
    cy.wrap($el).click() 
    })
}
else
{
cy.log ("NO Child element, skip step")
}
```

Comment: `cy.get(...).should(...)` doesn't return a boolean, it either throws an error (or otherwise fails the test, errors are a common way to implement test frameworks) or doesn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , could please eloborate on your comment , i didnt understand

Comment: @jonrsharpe using cy.get.should will fail test rather than going to else ?

Answer (score 0):

Your test will succeed if the specified condition is true only, otherwise will fail. `.should('have.descendants')` asserts that yielded subject `cy.get(parent)` has descendants and is awaiting to be true.
So I would suggest to:

```
let count;
cy.get(parent).then($el => {
    if ($el.find('.child-class-in-scope')) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        cy.log ("No ascendant elements found")
        count = 0
    }

    if (count === 1) {


     // closing child elements logic here


    } else {
        cy.log ("NO Child element, skip step")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Izbas, but even if there is no child class , count always set to 1 , any suggestion to try with length please

Comment: @GKannan could you try: `if ($el.find('.child-class-in-scope').length) { ... `

Comment: this worked for me  let count =     Cypress.$(child class selector).length if count ==0 { skip} else { logic for actions to all child elements };